# Gradle exclude subproject lib by jar name pattern

Tags: java, gradle

I have 5 subprojects in my gradle project. And I want to copy to a certain folder A all subproject libs except one that has in it's name string 'myproj3'
It became just a painful headache. Nothing works.

```
task copyNoSrVersionLibs(type: Copy, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
    from(subprojects.jar){
        exclude {
            details -> details.file.name.contains('myproj3')
        }
    }
    into project.file('build/libs/mylibs/lib')

}
```

I tried different forms, nothing works. The file is still in the folder
How to do that in gradle?

Comment: what about changing from "not copying to" to "delete from"?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you try to avoid the copy process which is complicated obviously, why not letting gradle copying the jar and then deleting it in a later lifecycle phase?

Comment: Thanks, but gradle is positioned like advanced build tool, just copy files with filters is complicated? Anyway, I think deletion is not less complicated